# Delete Multiple rows from datagridview

Tags: c#

I've a datagridview in which values are inserted.The gridview is like this.

```
    Item                PRID                 
   ------              ------               
    Item1                1
    Item2                2
    Item3                2
```

I am trying to compare the PRID with a variable which holds the selected row PRID.
What I've done so far.

```
                foreach (DataGridViewRow dgv_r in PurchaseOrder_dgv.Rows)
                {
                    if (dgv_r.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == CurrentSelected_PRID_ForPurchaseOrder.ToString())
                    {
                        PurchaseOrder_dgv.Rows.Remove(dgv_r);
                    }
                }
```

But it deletes the bottom row not the second row.and gives the following error.What I want is if the value of `CurrentSelected_PRID_ForPurchaseOrder` is equal to 2 then it should delete both the rows.I've tried it using for loop also but it gives me Index out of range error.It is giving the following error.

```
 Object Reference Not set to an instance of object
```

Comment: You didn't give the error, but it probably has something to do with removing elements during a `foreach`.  What is the underlying data source for the data grid?  Is it a database, from which you can remove the rows and rebind the grid?

Comment: it is just not deleting the row when there are three rows it deletes the bottom two and leaves the top 1.The data is being inserted in the gridview manually using for loop. I've update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are a couple of ways around this. One is to do the following

```
for (int i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (String.Compare(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), "2") == 0)
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[i]);
```

This is looping from the bottom end of the `DataGridView` and avoids the problem with removing rows whilst iterating.

I hope this helps.

Comment: if i try this it doesn't delete a single row.

Answer (score 0):

As mellamokb pointed out the reason is because your editing the collection during the foreach. One solution would be to store the rows with the same PRID in a list first and then remove them after. Something like this

```
var rowsToRemove = new List<int>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow dgv_r in PurchaseOrder_dgv.Rows)
{
    if (dgv_r.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == CurrentSelected_PRID_ForPurchaseOrder.ToString())
    {
        rowsToRemove.Add(dgv_r.Index);
    }
}

rowsToRemove.Reverse();
rowsToRemove.ForEach(i => PurchaseOrder_dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(i));
```

Another solution is to use a while loop instead which takes into account the possiblity of the collection size changing.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < PurchaseOrder_dgv.Rows.Count)
{
    if (PurchaseOrder_dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == CurrentSelected_PRID_ForPurchaseOrder.ToString())
    {
        PurchaseOrder_dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: from your first example it is not deleting a single row also just showing the error.

Comment: @Mj1992, sorry I've updated the second example, what error do you get in the for solution?