# reference and foreach loop on dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have `DataGrid` with `CheckBox` column. I want that by press a button all the checked row's will deleted. (i have special function for delete ) 
i search how to do this `foreach` loop and i  found this -

```
private void delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridDepartment.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn1.Name].Value) == true)
        {
            // get row number
            remove(list.ElementAt(rowNumber));
        }
    }
}
```

but, `DataGridViewRow` , `Rows` ,`CheckBoxColumn1` , `Cells` and `Value`  remains black. 
I tried to add `using System.Windows.Forms;` and the `DataGridViewRow` chenge his color but all the `MessageBox` and `UserControl` show error:

> MessageBox is an ambiguous reference between System.Windows.MessageBox
>   and System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox

these are my reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
```

what can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying row collection once iterating doesn't sound like a good plan. I assume that you don't exploit data binding here, so use the suggestion from this post instead ([Delete Multiple rows from datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804347/delete-multiple-rows-from-datagridview)).

Concerning references just make MessageBox reference disambiguous by

```
using MessageBox = System.Windows.MessageBox;
```

or call it explicitly

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(...)
```

UPDATE

The problem is different. You have System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid and you are trying to adapt some System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView code to it. These two are completely different and your code won't work.

You can check how to work with WPF DataGrid and data binding (e.g. http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html). WPF strongly relies on data binding and thus you in general should not access grid items (DataGrid.Items property) for CRUD operations and perform corresponding operations on DataGrid.ItemsSource directly as shown in example.

Comment: thank you!  its help.
but, the ".Rows" & ".Cells" & ".Value" still not recognize,  you know what can i do to change it?

Comment: DataGridViewRow  and all its specific child property types are members of System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: DataGridViewRow change is color' but all the other dont. and the ".Rows" send the error :
 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Your problem is different. You have System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid and you are trying to adapt some System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView code to it. These two are completely different and your code won't work.

Do you use any binding to DataGrid? How do you add rows you want to delete?

Comment: there is a file that in the first run is empty and the user add stuff. 
the binding to DataGrid is one of the list from the file. i want that by the CheckBox column the function will know which row to delete.  I just learned C# and WPF so I'm sorry if I have a basic mistakes and I hope I'm explaining myself clear.

Comment: You can check how to work with WPF Datagrid using for example the following article: http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

As you can see here WPF strongly relies on data binding and thus you in general should not access grid items (taht are noe in Rows but in Items property) for CRUD operations and perform corresponding operations on ItemsSource directly